# Macbook pro 2017 Internal SSD not recognized

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, startup, ssd, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my internal SSD from my Macbook Pro 2017 256GB to a 1TB SSD I found online. I bought it from Aliexpress and seemed genuine.

The fact is that my computer does not recognize it IN Disk Utility, however, it does boot from the 1TB SSD with the preinstalled OS and it detects it. But I wanted to upgrade to Catalina from Disk Utility it fails to show the SSD.

I tried resetting the SMC, PRAM, extract the SSD and mount it another time.
Finally I get a folder with a question mark error and a prohibition sign.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Mnd.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "it does boot from the 1TB SSD with the preinstalled OS" - then why not update it from there? What's the preinstalled OS?

Comment: The preinstalled OS is High Sierra I think, I did try to upgrade but from the recovery but it did not detect the SSD. I wanted to do this to make a clean install.